# Search priority for views using EmbeddedFileProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm have this code pulling views embedded as resource in my referenced assembly:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(SomeTypeInMyAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
    });
```

It successfully finds views in the embedded location (`Views\Shared\Components\ViewComponentName\Default.cshtml`). I need it to FIRST search for the files in the current project BEFORE looking at any assemblies, this way I can create defaults in an assembly, and allow "overrides" in the main project (same path). Anyone have any ideas how this can be done?  I'm still trying to look through the source to figure this out.

And no, `ViewLocationExpander` is not the answer.  I need to use the exact same path and file names, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are TWO options:

1. Add
   `options.FileProviders.Add(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider);`
   just before `EmbeddedFileProvider`.  (`HostingEnvironment` was simply taken
   from the `Startup()` constructor and stored locally in the `Startup` class. The physical file on disk (could also be in the cache) will be found before the assembly version.
2. Wrap `EmbeddedFileProvider` in your own type (implement `IFileProvider`) and pass in `IHostingEnvironment`. The `GetFileInfo()` method is
   called while trying to locate files.  The
   `IHostingEnvironment` instance is used to detect physical
   files from the root content path, and returns `NotFoundFileInfo` if a local file exists:

   ```
   public virtual IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
   {
       if (_HostingEnvironment != null)
       {
           var filepath = Path.Combine(_HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, subpath.TrimStart('/'));
           if (File.Exists(filepath))
               return new NotFoundFileInfo(filepath);
       }
       return _EmbeddedFileProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath)
   }
   ```

   and add it to `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

   ```
   services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.FileProviders.Add(new MyEmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(SomeTypeInTheTargetAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, HostingEnvironment));
       });
    }
   ```